# Loop through multiple excel worksheets within a workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Here is a piece of code which I have written to do a formatting task on various excel files in a particular folder. However the problem is this only runs on the 1st worksheet of all excel workbooks in that folder. I am not able to loop through all the individual worksheets of all the excel files. Please help me edit the code. Thanks

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Change the layout
Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With

'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Put the code that uses `ActiveSheet` in a `For Each` loop that loops over `wb.Worksheets`.

Answer (score 0):

ou need to loop through all sheets in workbook, added also `Dim sht as Worksheet`

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    ' added this line, loop through all worksheets in current wb
    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets

        'Change the layout
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
        With sht.PageSetup
            .PrintTitleRows = ""
            .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        End With
        Application.PrintCommunication = True
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
        With sht.PageSetup
            .LeftHeader = ""
            .CenterHeader = ""
            .RightHeader = ""
            .LeftFooter = ""
            .CenterFooter = ""
            .RightFooter = ""
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .PrintHeadings = False
            .PrintGridlines = False
            .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
            .PrintQuality = 600
            .CenterHorizontally = False
            .CenterVertically = False
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Draft = False
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
            .Order = xlDownThenOver
            .BlackAndWhite = False
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = False
            .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
            .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
            .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
            .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
            .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
            .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        End With
    Next sht

    'Save and Close Workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The above code works perfectly for the first 2 sheets but no changes are made to the 3rd sheet of all the excel files, is there something we missed?

Comment: are the rest of your worksheets hidden ? just tested the code on My PC and it's working fine